# how to encoding string in chiness and koren language?

Tags: iphone

I want to encode strings in to the Chinese and Korean languages how it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible using UTF16 and if needed surrogate characters, UTF32 and UTF8 also can bear it.

more info about encodings:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Comment: Can u give me in details if possible?

Comment: have u read the wiki article? take a look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237565/iphone-cgcontextshowtextatpoint-for-japanese-characters