# NSString UTF8String mangling unicode characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When I run `[NSString UTF8String]` on certain unicode characters the resulting `const char*` representation is mangled both in `NSLog` and on the device/simulator display. The `NSString` itself displays fine but I need to convert the `NSString` to a `cStr` to use it in `CGContextShowTextAtPoint`.

It's very easy to reproduce (see code below) but I've searched for similar questions without any luck. Must be something basic I'm missing.

```
const char *cStr = [@"章" UTF8String];
NSLog(@"%s", cStr);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Good to know about the issue with %s. Ultimately though what I need is for the text to appear on the display correctly. And the crux of the problem is that I need to display the string with kerning. I've looked on SO and there are some good answers on how to do this. But they all require I use CGContextShowTextAtPoint for the character spacing. If I can't use CGContextShowTextAtPoint for unicode chars does anyone know how I would adjust inter-character spacing using another means that keeps all my unicode chars unchanged?

Answer (score 2):

`CGContextShowTextAtPoint` is only for ASCII chars.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237565/iphone-cgcontextshowtextatpoint-for-japanese-characters) SO question for answers.

Answer (score 1):

When using the string format specifier (aka %s) you cannot be guaranteed that the characters of a c string will print correctly if they are not ASCII.  Using a complex character as you've defined can be expressed in UTF-8 using escape characters to indicate the character set from which the character can be found.  However the %s uses the system encoding to interpret the characters in the character string you provide to the formatting ( in this case, in NSLog ).  See Apple's documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

%s
Null-terminated array of 8-bit unsigned characters. %s interprets its input in the system encoding rather than, for example, UTF-8.

Going onto you CGContextShowTextAtPoint not working, that API supports only the macRoman character set, which is not the entire Unicode character set.

Youll need to look into another API for showing Unicode characters.  Probably Core Text is where you'll want to start.

Answer (score 1):

I've never noticed this issue before, but some quick experimentation shows that using `printf` instead of `NSLog` will cause the correct Unicode character to show up.

Try:

```
printf("%s", cStr);
```

This gives me the desired output ("章") both in the Xcode console and in Terminal. As nob1984 stated in his answer, the interpretation of the character data is up to the callee.